# how to check value associated with radio buttons through jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, dhtml

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#esp").click(function(){ 
        $(".auth_type").slideDown("normal");
        $("#no").click(function(){
             $(".auth_other").slideUp("normal");                     
        });
        $("#yes").click(function(){
             $(".auth_other").slideDown("normal");           
        });
   });
            
   $("#ah").click(function(){ 
        $(".auth_type").slideUp("normal");

   });
});
```

there are two radio buttons on my web page with id **(#ah)** and id **(#esp)**

**1.**  when user click on **esp radio button** then a table row with **class(auth_type)** should appear.It also have two radio buttons in it with id **no** and id **yes**

if user clicks **yes** then further a table row with **class (auth_other)** should appear and if **no** selected then it should disappear

**2.** when user clicks on **ah radio button** the then table row with **class (auth_type)** should disappear.

Everything is working fine also now problem is that when when user have selected **no** and clicked on **ah radio button also**  then table row with class **auth_other** is appeared which should not be .

I tried to handle it and added following lines to the jquery code for **esp radio button**

```
var sel = $(":radio[name='auth_opt']:checked").val();   

if(sel=='n')
     $(".auth_type").slideDown("normal");
```

but din't worked ...

I thought that when user clicked **no** as wll as **ah** then i should make it forcefully appeared .

#### Is there any mechanism by which i can force the radio buttons with class **"auth_type"** to  be checked by default on **"yes"** button whenever user clicked on **"ah"** or from **"ah"** to back on **"esp"**.I think that may solve the problem.

I am new to jquery but have worked with javascript so if someone could tell me Is there something wrong with the above jquery code??

The Whole HTML code is very long so just showing the HTML for the class "auth_type" .
If needed i will add the code for class "auth_other" also.

```
..
....
<tr class="auth_type" style="display:none">
<td width="400" height="40">Apply Authentication</td>
<td>
  <table width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td style="text-align:center">
  <input type="radio" name="auth_opt" value="y" id="yes" align="left" checked="checked" />yes
  </td>

  <td style="text-align:center">
  <input type="radio" name="auth_opt" value="n" id="no" align="right"/>no
  </td>

  </tr>
  </table>


  </td>
  </tr>
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to concern yourself with the `#yes` and `#no` button specifically. You just need to say "when one of the radio buttons inside `.auth_type` is clicked, hide or show the `.auth_other` row depending on which of the two buttons it was". This is what this code does:

```
$(".auth_type input:radio").click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "y") {
        $(".auth_other").slideDown("normal");                     
    }
    else {
        $(".auth_other").slideUp("normal");                     
    }
});
```

Also, you should **not** put the code that attaches the `click` event handlers inside the `#esp` click handler itself:

```
$("#esp").click(function(){ 
    $(".auth_type").slideDown("normal");

    // NOT IN HERE!
});

// OUT HERE IS CORRECT
$(".auth_type input:radio").click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "y") {
        $(".auth_other").slideDown("normal");                     
    }
    else {
        $(".auth_other").slideUp("normal");                     
    }
});
```

From what you describe, you might also want to hide the `.auth_other` when the `#ah` radio is selected (it might be showing from an earlier user interaction):

```
$("#ah").click(function(){ 
     $(".auth_type").add(".auth_other").slideUp("normal");
});
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/USdyM/)**.

Comment: Thanx but the last one you have described is not what i want.i need to display `.auth_other` whenever `#ah` radio is selected except for the case when `#no` is activated and this is d main problem rest all is working fine. also another thing i want is when user click back on `#esp` (assume currently `#ah` active) then by default `#yes` should be active.

Comment: @UditGupta: This is all a very confusing affairs -- so to make `.auth_other` appear you have to first select `#esp` (and `#yes`), but then when you deselect `#esp` and select `#ah` the `.auth_other` remains visible? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I agree actually this is an ipsec front hand implementation.. ah(authentication header) and esp(encapsulated security payload)

Comment: Now by default `ah` is activated and so `.auth_other`(options n field for authentication).when esp is selected then `.auth_type` appear to ask for wheteher authentication is needed or not (authentication is optional in esp while encryption is must).if yes then `.auth_other` appear otherwise disappear.Now if it makes any sense.I am just looking fr an answer if someone could tell me Can I make `#yes` to be active if user clicks on `#ah` .

Comment: Okkkkkk.....I got the answer this is how anyone can make the radio button to be checked or unchecked from the jquery code.

`var presetValue = "y";`
        `$([name=auth_opt]").filter([value="+presetValue+"]").attr("checked","checked");`

Now when `#esp` 
is selected it will make `#yes` button default checked every time.

Anyways thanks for your valuable suggestions.